# copy files to a new name - shortest way

Tags: files, rename, file-copy

In a directory, I have about 150 files with a certain extension, for example:

```
abc.ext
def.ext
ghi.ext
...
```

Now I want to copy all of these files also to a new filename (without extension):

```
abc
def
ghi
```

What is the shortest way to get this done? Is it possible without writing a loop in a bash file?

Edit: Thank you for your answers (dirkt, John Newman).
After seeing the answers I'll stick with the shorter one, although it has a loop.

Comment: With `zsh`: `autoload zmv; zmv -C -n '(*).ext' '$1'` (remove the `-n` if you like what you see...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible without writing a script ("bash file"), but not without using a loop:

```
for f in *.ext ; do cp -- "$f" "$(basename "$f" .ext)" ; done
```

`basename` can be used to remove the suffix.

Comment: Be sure to quote your variables, lest one of those names have, say, a space in them

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible without a loop. Is it good ... I'll leave that up to you.

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.ext" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} echo cp -T {} {}SUB | sed -e 's/\.extSUB//g'
```

append a pipe to sh to get out of dry run mode. Backticks are no good as it strips the newlines, unless you deal with $IFS.  And there are other character issues with backticks as mentioned. Also need the cp -T as the last argument is normally expecting a directory.

I don't have enough "rep" to comment on the above, but you can use various tricks with bash `${}` to avoid the fork of `basename`.

Substring: `${f:0:-4}`
or longest match: `${f%%.ext}`

Comment: Without the echo, what would be getting piped to `sed`?  Also, without the `echo` wouldn't the `cp` happen before you strip the extra text from the end?

Comment: you're correct .. i obviously never bothered to try that.  i edited it.

Comment: Although using backticks (or `$()`) will rebreak things if there are unsafe characters in the filenames, which you were protecting against with `-print0`

Comment: edited again AND actually fully tested it this time.  harder than I thought.  backticks strip the new lines.

Comment: Sadly, this still fails for my file `with a space.ext` and also `$'new\nline.ext'`

Comment: And yeah, handling filenames can be a major major pain, especially when they aren't well behaved!

Comment: Yeah, we have a company wide policy, "no spaces in file names!!!"
I think you could probably put quotes around the "{}" "{}" to handle spaces, but I won't. 

I just use a simple `for i in * ; do mv $i ${i%%ext} ; done` when I have to do this and be done in 10 seconds.  This question to "avoid a loop" has wasted 30 minutes of my life..

Comment: Quoting the arguments to `xargs` won't help, you need to get the `echo` to output quotes and the `sed` to preserve them. Simpler: just do `find ... -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%%.ext}"' findsh {} \;` or similar (fixed)